# how to change default email address for postfix?

Tags: postfix-mta

I have a server running python, php, perl, ruby, and I have couple applications which also send mail. I was wondering in case if one of the applications don't specify a from email address, the sender email address is set to `http@example.com` and the sender name was "http".

I was able change the sender name by going into `/etc/passwd` and changing the name to what I wanted, but how do I change `http@example.com` to `admin@example.com`?

Comment: You would probably get a better response if you ask this on http://superuser.com/ which is one of StackOverflow's many sister sites - and more tailored to your question.

Answer (score 40):

You can use the [smtp_generic_maps](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#smtp_generic_maps) of postfix to rewrite email headers for outgoing smtp mail:

```
user:~$ echo "http@example.com  admin@example.com" >> /etc/postfix/generic 
user:~$ echo "smtp_generic_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/generic" >> /etc/postfix/main.cf
user:~$ postmap /etc/postfix/generic
user:~$ service postfix restart
```

Comment: echo "http@example.com   admin@example.com" >> /etc/postfix/generic might be easier for many to read.

Comment: @knittl What about also overriding sender name? It works but send email as "fromme@example.com(root)". Almost there, but not quite

Comment: "postmap: warning: /etc/postfix/generic, line 1: expected format: key whitespace value"

Comment: You can also skip the command `postmap /etc/postfix/generic` and tell main.cf that you use a `texthash` instead of a `hash`: `echo "smtp_generic_maps = texthash:/etc/postfix/generic" >> /etc/postfix/main.cf`